# shopping cart listed price is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

```
var IndexCoffe = ["Espresso Coffee", "Toraja Coffe", "Mocha Latte", "Kona Coffee"];

var next = document.getElementById("next");

var slideText = 0;

var names = document.getElementById("nameCoffee");

var count = 0;

var countButton = document.getElementById("plus");

var display = document.getElementById("number");

var displayPrice = document.getElementById("price");

function nextItem(){
    slideText += 1;
    slideText = slideText % IndexCoffe.length;
    return IndexCoffe[slideText];
}

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    names.innerHTML = nextItem();
});

countButton.onclick = function(){
    // var IndexCoffe = ["Espresso Coffee", "Toraja Coffe", "Mocha Latte", "Kona Coffee"];
    count++;
    var res;
    for(var i=0; i<IndexCoffe.length; i++)
    {
        if(IndexCoffe[i].localeCompare("Espresso Coffee")){
            res = count * 2.10;
            display.innerHTML = count;
            displayPrice.innerHTML = res.toFixed(2);
        }
        if(IndexCoffe[i].localeCompare("Toraja Coffe")){
            var res2 = count * 3.40;
            display.innerHTML = count;
            displayPrice.innerHTML = res2.toFixed(2);
        }
        if(IndexCoffe[i].localeCompare("Mocha Latte")){
            var res3 = count * 2.50;
            display.innerHTML = count;
            displayPrice.innerHTML = res3.toFixed(2);
        }
        if(IndexCoffe[i].localeCompare("Kona Coffee")){
            var res4 = count * 4.00;
            display.innerHTML = count;
            displayPrice.innerHTML = res4.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the + and button, I don't know why the listed price is only at 2.50. Even though I want the coffee name listed to be different, the price will be different when I click the + and - buttons. The comments are just examples of the  arrays.

Comment: It would be easy to understand of you could add HTML also

Comment: You are overwriting `displayPrice.innerHTML` in each condition and at each step of the loop... so, you'll just see the last condition that was satisfied at the last step of the loop result.